# json.Unmarshal returning blank structure

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a JSON blob that looks like this

```
{
    "metadata":{
        "id":"2377f625-619b-4e20-90af-9a6cbfb80040",
        "from":"2014-12-30T07:23:42.000Z",
        "to":"2015-01-14T05:11:51.000Z",
        "entryCount":801,
        "size":821472,
        "deprecated":false
    },
    "status":[{
         "node_id":"de713614-be3d-4c39-a3f8-1154957e46a6",
         "status":"PUBLISHED"
    }]
}
```

and I have a little code to transform that back into go structs

```
type Status struct {
    status string
    node_id string
}

type Meta struct {
    to string
    from string
    id string
    entryCount int64
    size int64
    depricated bool
}

type Mydata struct {
    met meta
    stat []status
}

var realdata Mydata
err1 := json.Unmarshal(data, &realdata)
if err1 != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err1)
}
fmt.Printf("%T: %+v\n", realdata, realdata)
```

but what I see when I run this is just a zeroed structure

```
main.Mydata: {met:{to: from: id: entryCount:0 size:0 depricated:false} stat:[]}
```

I tried allocating the struct first but that also didn't work, I'm not sure why its not producing values, and its not returning an error

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Your struct fields are not exported. This is because they start with a lowercase letter.

```
EntryCount // <--- Exported
entryCount // <--- Not exported
```

When I say "not exported", I mean they are not visible outside of your package. Your package can happily access them because they are scoped locally to it.

As for the `encoding/json` package though - it cannot see them. You need to make all of your fields visible to the `encoding/json` package by making them all start with an uppercase letter, thereby exporting them:

```
type Status struct {
    Status  string
    Node_id string
}

type Meta struct {
    To         string
    From       string
    Id         string
    EntryCount int64
    Size       int64
    Depricated bool
}

type Mydata struct {
    Metadata  Meta
    Status []Status
}
```

<kbd>[See it working on the Go Playground here](http://play.golang.org/p/adZgg_x4j3)</kbd>

You should also reference the Golang specification for answers. Specifically, [the part that talks about Exported Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Comment: This should not be downvoted, but you should mention the json tag values for giving the marshaled json a desired name.  like `json:"entry_count"`

Comment: Apologies. Fixed. I wrote this after heavy code discussions at work (where I am a .NET developer).

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because it helped me. But man does it make me cranky.