# How to decode embedded json?

Tags: json, go

I can't decode the m into values even though it's a nested map and I provided struct filed of type map. I don't understand why ?

most of the problems was in the struct fields
I didn't **capitalize** it's names so they were not exported

```
    id  int //it should be Id  
    values map[interface{}]interface{}//should be Values
```

and the map keys shouldn't be of type interface it should be of type **string**

```
Values map[interface{}]interface{}
//should be Values map[string]interface{}
```

the filed name didn't match the json keys you can solve
this problem using the **struct tags** or by **matching them with json keys**

```
//the key for the embedded object was m .
// was trying to decode it into struct 
//field and it's name was m .it was like this before fixing it  
type edit struct{
  Id int 
  Values [interface{}]interface{}
}
//and json object was like this 
{
  "id":5,
  "m": {"name":"alice"}
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)
type edit struct {
    Id  int 
    Values map[string]interface{}
 
 
}
func main() {
    a := `{
        "id":5,
        "values":{
        "name":"alice"
        }
}`
    var s edit
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(a))
    err := dec.Decode(&s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

[Play good code](https://play.golang.org/p/U29DAeVNSCH)

Comment: There are two issues.  (1) Export the fields. See [json.Marshal(struct) returns “{}”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26327436/5728991) for more info. (2) The structure of the JSON should match the structure of the Go types.  Rename field `values` to `m` to match the JSON.

Comment: You can't json unmarshal into a map using `interface{}` as a key type. Also, `id` is a string not an `int`. Fix: https://play.golang.org/p/bXaUyQzDmAi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json.Unmarshal returning blank structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228393/json-unmarshal-returning-blank-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

1. First of all, all the fields of your `edit` struct must be *exported* which means you should capitalize the first letter of every fields. 
   Just like the following:

   ```golang
   type edit struct {
       Id
       Values
   }
   ```
2. The data type of of `key` of the `Values` field must be string to be able to decode the `json` data.

   ```golang
   type edit struct {
       Id     int
       Values map[string]interface{}
   }
   ```
3. Finally, data type of your `json` data `"id"` is wrong. It must be `int` to be matched to your `Go` struct. Also, there is no `"m"` defined in your struct. The `"m"` must be replaced with `"values"` to match your `Go` struct. Just like the following

   ```json
   {
       "id": 5,
       "values":{
           "name": "alice"
       }
   }
   ```

Just to let you know, you can simply use following piece of code to unmarshal `json` data into `Go` struct.

```golang
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), &s)
```

Comment: thnaks for your helpful answer .